# What does 'parent=structure' do?

Tags: fonts, beamer

I came across this code.

```
\setbeamerfont{foo}{size=\huge,parent=structure}
```

What does `parent=structure` do exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## For colors

According to the `beamer` manual, in the context of colors, `structure` is a `beamer` color in which all sorts of elements inherit from it.

The name reflects its meaning in the template: it's the structure. `:)` For example, when using `\usecolortheme{default}`, the main colors set in the theme are the following (from the manual):

- `normal text` is black on white.
- `alerted text` is red.
- `example text` is a dark green (green with 50% black).
- `structure` is set to a light version of `MidnightBlue` (more precisely, `20% red`, `20% green`, and `70% blue`).

When we use `parent=structure`, we set the element color to derive from the `structure` color. If we alter the color theme, the derived color will also reflect the change.

## For fonts

Now, for the context of fonts, which is our case, `structure` is the base font setting in which all sorts of elements inherit from it. If we use `\usefonttheme{serif}`, for example:

- `structure` is set to `beamer`'s serif font.

Then, similarly, when we use `parent=structure`, we set the element font to derive from the `structure` font. If we alter the font theme, the derived font will also reflect the change.

Comment: Your answer was very clear, but there is one thing I still don't understand: `\setbeamerfont` is meant to change fonts, not colours (there is `\setbeamercolor` for that). Yet in this case, we seem to be inheriting a colour property via `\setbeamerfont`..

Comment: @EdwardStumperd: I checked it again and found out that `structure` is also defined in the context of fonts. It's similar to the `color` idea: the font theme sets the `structure`, which holds the default font setting for that theme. When we use `parent=structure`, we are inheriting the base font setting. I wrote an addendum to my answer, I hope it's better now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Once again a very clear explanation.